# Call WSDL soap method in iPhone

Tags: iphone

i am working on an iPhone project in which i have a wsdl which is having description of methods and these methods contains an xml. I need to call these methods which are there in wsdl to get the xml using soap and parse it. I have read so many links and tutorials but was not able to to call the method in the wsdl. Please if u can provide me some links or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://sudzc.com/ ,it gives you ready WSDL

This is a .NET web site solution that uses XSLT to transform SOAP-based web service definition WSDL files into complete code packages. The code that is generated is easy to read and update.

While SudzC supports multiple platforms, it's focus is on code generation for Objective-C libraries for iPhone development.

reference http://code.google.com/p/sudzc/

Comment: Hi i have tried soapui software and got the methods of wsdl and when click on a particular method it shows request1 and when click on request1 it shows an xml. Now i pass some parameters in the xml and run it. on running it shows the real xml. Now this whole process i have to do in iphone to get the real xml.

Comment: try wsdl created by sudzc,its real easy to make requests,you just need to add generated code files to your project

Comment: i tried that also but there is no option to download the code also some files are coming blank in it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. It worked for me.

[Note: GetDictionary is my method name which is displayed in Web service.and in url please write the url displayed in web service at below portion. It should be matched with url you have written in coding otherwise you will not get output(better copy it from web service)]

```
-(IBAction)loadData
{

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<SOAP-ENV:Body>\n"
                         "<GetDictionary></GetDictionary>\n"
                         "</SOAP-ENV:Body>\n"
                         "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://c70.narolainfotech.local/WCFTest/RestServiceImpl.svc/basic"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"urn:RestServiceImpl/GetDictionary" forHTTPHeaderField:@"soapAction"];
// [theRequest addValue: @"urn:RestServiceImpl/getDataBY_ID" forHTTPHeaderField:@"soapAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

   if(theConnection)
   {
      webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
   }
   else
   {
      NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}
```

In connectionDidFinishLoading write following code:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);


NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"result : %@",strData);

NSString *result=nil;
NSString *str;

NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"];
theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"];
theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
//NSLog(@"XML from Web-Service ======= \n\n %@",theXML);

NSArray *array=[theXML componentsSeparatedByString:@"<GetDictionaryResult>"];
for(int i=1;i<[array count];i++)
{
    str=[array objectAtIndex:i];

    NSRange ranfrom=[str rangeOfString:@"</GetDictionaryResult>"];
    result =[str substringToIndex:ranfrom.location];
}
NSLog(@"result ::: %@",result);
}
```

Just Hope that it'll work for you. :)

Comment: Hi Panu_Parekh i don't have the url i am having only wsdl in which a method named GetItemsiOS is there. I have to call this method and this method contains xml. So i have to request and pass some parameters and in response i get that xml data. So i have to call wsdl then call the method  and get the xml data.